# How to add event handlers within const in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm doing a react project with PRIMER React template. In the sign in page, the code as follows.

```
const Signin = (props) => {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
              <form>
                <TextField
                  id="username"
                  label="Username"
                  className={classes.textField}
                  fullWidth
                  margin="normal"
                />
                <TextField
                  id="password"
                  label="Password"
                  className={classes.textField}
                  type="password"
                  fullWidth
                  margin="normal"
                />
                <Button variant="raised" color="primary" fullWidth type="submit">Login</Button>
              </form>
  );
}
```

I need to add the form Submit event handler. So I added that code as follows.

```
const Signin = (props) => {
      const { classes } = props;

      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

        handleSubmit(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          const data = new FormData(event.target);

          this.setState({
            res: data
          });
        console.log(this.state.res)
      }

      return (
                  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <TextField
                      id="username"
                      label="Username"
                      className={classes.textField}
                      fullWidth
                      margin="normal"
                    />
                    <TextField
                      id="password"
                      label="Password"
                      className={classes.textField}
                      type="password"
                      fullWidth
                      margin="normal"
                    />
                    <Button variant="raised" color="primary" fullWidth type="submit">Login</Button>
                  </form>
      );
    }
```

But this is not working. I can't even compile this. Whats the wrong here and How can I manage event handlers??

Comment: You don't need this line `this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);` and need to change `<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>` to `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>` and make `handleSubmit` as `arrow function.

Comment: You can't use `this` for stateless functional components. You'll need to turn it into a full blown component class.

Comment: Why do you use a stateless component while you need to use its state?..

Comment: @Arfeo I don't. But I don't know how to use event handler in stateless components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component is a functional component. So do the followings and run once :

1. remove `this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);`
2. event `handleSubmit` place it like a `const handleSubmit = (e) => {}`  or place it outside the component and `setState` - **make it as a class component.Still you need functional component, use hooks or use refs** inside stateless components.
3. change `<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>` to `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>`

Either, you can use class component for this case `Signin`  if your intention is to use setState. to Converting a Function to a Class check [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

and in functional component you can define ref like this:

```
 <input type='text' placeholder='Enter City Name'
    ref={ el => cityInput = el } />
```

and in submit you can get it's value like:

```
cityInput.value
```

Example Functoinal Component :

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  let cityInput

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    let city = cityInput.value
    if (city) {
      console.log(city)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={ onSubmit }>
        <div>
          <input type='text' placeholder='Enter City Name'
            ref={ el => cityInput = el } />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>Go</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ylskqo)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error is because you're mixing regular function/class syntax with arrrow syntax.

Remember arrows function have no "this" or calling context so you'll need to make that changes at mentioned by Panther. All the best.

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions for more details

actually I see you're using state in the component.

You'll have to convert it into a class or instead use a hook

```
const [formRes, setformRes] = React.UseState();

handleSubmit(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   const data = new FormData(event.target);

   setformRes(data)
   console.log(formRes)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. use class component.
2. Pass down the eventHandler function from Parent component.

functional component supposed to return some JSX. if you want do some mess staff, class component will be better!